# Time Complexity of Bliss Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

In the function that I created, I am using canonical_label method described here
http://www.tcs.tkk.fi/Software/bliss/index.html
So in order to compute time complexity for my algorithm, I need to know the time complexity of the previously implemented Bliss Algorithm, described in the link above.

Can someone help me with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use it as a black box, you may state the overall complexity as, for example, $O(n^2 \cdot Bliss(n, m))$ (that is, your algorithm is calling Bliss $n^2$ times). Since Bliss is a more a practical tool than a theoretical algorithm, it is possible that it its complexity is not fully known due to some complex heuristics. They work good in practice but their big-O complexity can be hard to deterimine.

Comment: See http://cneurocvs.rmki.kfki.hu/igraph/doc/html/igraph_canonical_permutation.html. _Time complexity: exponential, in practice it is fast for many graphs._